# How to show and hide multiple forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have three forms. Lets say that they are `Form1`, `Form2` and `Form3`. And `Form3` can be opened through `Form1` or `Form2`. Everytime I show `Form3` (form3.Show();) I hide `Form1` or `Form2`.

How can I show again `Form1` when I close `Form3`, if `Form3` is opened via `Form1`?

And then show `Form2` when I close `Form3`, if `Form3` is opened via `Form2`?

Comment: When you say "getting back to": Do you mean changing the Focus? Do you mean one should be a modal dialog to another? Do you mean like Navigating a Webpage?

Comment: everytime i open form3 i close form1 or form2. going back to form1 or form2 means opening the form again and closing form3.

Comment: Instead of closing Form1/Form2 just hide them then when you close Form3 you just unhide Form1/Form2.

Comment: As Handbag Said, hiding/unhiding is a option. As would be just rec-reation. However that raises a bigger question: How do you exchange the data between Forms? And I mean stuff like the Form Reference (to unhide) or the data you use to initilaize the new Form3 instance with old values. WinForms never had any native support for that, so you have to coblle something together. WPF is way better in this regard.

Comment: @HandbagCrab How would the program know if form3 is accessed through form1 or form2? because if form3 is accessed through form1, upon closing form3 i want to show form1 again. And if form3 is accessed through form2, upon closing form3 i want to show form2 again.

Comment: Open Form3 with ShowDialog(). This blocks the GUI thread on Form1/2 then when you close Form3 control passes back to Form1/2 and you can unhide it.

Comment: I've added an answer to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following method on Form1 and Form2. When you want to show Form3 you call this method:

```
public void ShowForm3()
{
    this.Hide();
    using (Form3 f3 = new Form3())
    {
        f3.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

It will hide the current form, instantiate and show Form3 then when Form3 is closed it will re-show the current form.

Comment: As a user, I would find this behaviour _very_ strange.

Comment: It's what OP wants.